# Classical toy models of particles with intrinsic spin

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, differential-geometry, quantum-spin, action

Related to my question here ([spacetime torsion, the spin tensor, and intrinsic spin in einstein cartan theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/137738/spacetime-torsion-the-spin-tensor-and-intrinsic-spin-in-einstein-cartan-theory)), I'd like to be able to put test particles on a manifold with non-zero torsion and see how this affects the motion.

The action for a free particle is usually given as:

$$S_{free} = -m\int d\tau = - m\int \sqrt{\frac{\partial x^\mu(\lambda)}{\partial \lambda}\frac{\partial x^\nu(\lambda)}{\partial \lambda}g_{\mu\nu}(\lambda)}\ \ d\lambda$$
where $\tau$ is the world line length, and $\lambda$ is some parameter to describe the particle path $x^\mu(\lambda)$.  I assume this is a scalar particle, since rotations will not affect its description.

1. Is there a term I am leaving out if we consider non-zero torsion?
2. What is the corresponding model for a free spinor particle? (I've seen classical spinor *fields* discussed, but never a particle)
3. What about for higher spin?
4. What about for arbitrary spin? (or even in classical models, are we limited to representations of the manifold tangent space?)

Answer (score 1):

Note that in classical systems, spin is not quantized but just a parameter, so the question of ''higher spin'' is not really meaningful. There remains only the question of statistics.

Lagrangian principles for classical Fermions were first discussed in: 
J.L. Martin, 
[Generalized classical dynamics, and the ‘classical analogue’ of a Fermioscillator](http://rspa.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/251/1267/536.short), Proc. R. Soc. Lond. A 251 (1959), 536-542.