# Why is it so coincident that Palatini variation of Einstein-Hilbert action will obtain an equation that connection is Levi-Civita connection?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, lagrangian-formalism, differential-geometry, variational-principle

There are two ways to do the variation of [Einstein-Hilbert action](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein%E2%80%93Hilbert_action).

First one is Einstein formalism which takes only metric independent. After variation of action, we get the Einstein field equation.
Second one is [Palatini formalism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palatini_variation) which takes metric and connection are independent. After variation, we get two equations, first is field equation and second is that connection is Levi-Civita connection.

So my question is why it is so coincident that Palatini variation of Einstein-Hilbert action will obtain an equation that connection is Levi-Civita connection and Palatini formalism coincides with Einstein formalism? While for $f(R)$ action they are generally different. Are there some deeper mathematical or physical structures of Einstein-Hilbert action which can account for it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I) In [Palatini](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F(R)_gravity) $f(R)$ [gravity](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/F%28R%29_theories_of_gravitation), the Lagrangian density is$^1$

$$ {\cal L}(g,\Gamma)~=~ \frac{1}{2\kappa}\sqrt{-g} f(R) + {\cal L}_{\rm m}; \tag{1}$$

with matter Lagrangian density ${\cal L}_{\rm m}$;
with [scalar curvature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_curvature)

$$R~:=~ g^{\mu\nu} R_{\mu\nu}(\Gamma);\tag{2}$$

with [Ricci curvature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricci_curvature) $R_{\mu\nu}(\Gamma)$; and where

$$\Gamma^{\lambda}_{\mu\nu}~=~\Gamma^{\lambda}_{\nu\mu}\tag{3}$$

is an arbitrary torsionfree$^2$ connection.

II) As OP mentions, the word *Palatini* refers to that the metric $g_{\mu\nu}$ and the connection $\Gamma^{\lambda}_{\mu\nu}$ are *independent* variables$^3$. We therefore get two types of [EL equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation):

1. The EL equations 
   $$ f^{\prime}(R)R_{\mu\nu} -\frac{1}{2}f(R)g_{\mu\nu}~\stackrel{(1)+(5)}{\approx}~\kappa T_{\mu\nu} \tag{4}$$
   for the metric $g_{\mu\nu}$ are the generalization of [EFE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_field_equations), where 
   $$T^{\mu\nu}~:=~\frac{2}{\sqrt{-g}}\frac{\delta S_{\rm m}}{\delta g_{\mu\nu}} \tag{5} $$
   is the matter Hilbert [stress-energy-momentum (SEM) tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor). 
   [In eq. (4) the $\approx$ symbol means equality modulo equations of motion. In this answer, we use $(-,+,\ldots,+)$ Minkowski sign convention in $d$ spacetime dimensions.]
2. If the matter action $S_{\rm m}$ doesn't depend on the connection $\Gamma^{\lambda}_{\mu\nu}$, then the EL equations 
   $$  \nabla_{\lambda}\hat{\mathfrak{g}}^{\mu\nu}
   ~\stackrel{(1)}{\approx}~0,\qquad 
   \hat{\mathfrak{g}}^{\mu\nu}
   ~:=~\sqrt{-g} f^{\prime}(R) g^{\mu\nu}
   ~\stackrel{(8)}{=}~\sqrt{-\hat{g}}  \hat{g}^{\mu\nu}, \tag{6}$$
   for the connection $\Gamma^{\lambda}_{\mu\nu}$ turn out to be the metric compatibility condition 
   $$\nabla_{\lambda}\hat{g}_{\mu\nu} ~\stackrel{(6)+(8)}{\approx}~0\tag{7}$$
   for a [conformally equivalent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_geometry) metric
   $$ \hat{g}_{\mu\nu}~:=~f^{\prime}(R)^{\frac{2}{d-2}} g_{\mu\nu}, \tag{8}$$
   known as the [Einstein frame metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_and_Einstein_frames).
   In other words, the classical solution for $\Gamma^{\lambda}_{\mu\nu}$ is the [Levi-Civita connection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_connection) for the Einstein frame metric $\hat{g}_{\mu\nu}$.

III) So Einstein gravity (GR) with a possible cosmological constant

$$ f(R)~=~R-2\Lambda,\tag{9} $$

or equivalently

$$ f^{\prime}(R)~=~1,\tag{10}$$

corresponds to the special case where the two metrics $g_{\mu\nu}$ and $\hat{g}_{\mu\nu}$ coincide, and hence $\Gamma^{\lambda}_{\mu\nu}$ becomes the Levi-Civita connection for $g_{\mu\nu}$.

--

$^1$ It is natural to replace the Lagrangian density (1) with the extended Lagrangian density

$$ \tilde{\cal L}(g,\Gamma,\Phi)~=~ \frac{1}{2\kappa}\sqrt{-g}\{\Phi R-V(\Phi)\} + {\cal L}_{\rm m}; \tag{11}$$

with auxiliary scalar [dilaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilaton) field $\Phi$; and where the potential

$$V(\Phi)~:=~\sup_r(\Phi r -f(r))\tag{12}$$

is the [Legendre transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_transformation) of the function $f$. If we integrate out the auxiliary scalar field $\Phi$, we then return to the $f(R)$ Lagrangian density (1) which we started from! The EL equations

$$  \nabla_{\lambda}\hat{\mathfrak{g}}^{\mu\nu}
~\stackrel{(1)}{\approx}~0,\qquad 
\hat{\mathfrak{g}}^{\mu\nu}
~:=~\sqrt{-g} \Phi g^{\mu\nu}
~\stackrel{(14)}{=}~\sqrt{-\hat{g}}  \hat{g}^{\mu\nu}, \tag{13}$$

for the connection $\Gamma^{\lambda}_{\mu\nu}$ become the metric compatibility condition (7) for the Einstein frame metric

$$ \hat{g}_{\mu\nu}~:=~\Phi^{\frac{2}{d-2}} g_{\mu\nu}. \tag{14}$$

After the connection $\Gamma^{\lambda}_{\mu\nu}$ has been integrated out, the Lagrangian density (11) becomes

$$ \tilde{\cal L}(g,\Phi)~=~ \frac{1}{2\kappa}\sqrt{-\hat{g}}\{R(\hat{g})-\Phi^{\frac{d}{2-d}}V(\Phi)\} + {\cal L}_{\rm m} , \tag{15}$$

where eq. (14) is implicitly assumed.

However, unfortunately the Legendre transform $V$ does not exist for Einstein gravity (9), so we will not consider the extended Lagrangian density (11) further in this answer.

$^2$ One could allow a non-dynamical torsion piece, but we will not pursue this here for simplicity. For more on [torsion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsion_tensor), see e.g. also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/137738/2451) Phys.SE post.

$^3$ Normally in non-Palatini formulations, we integrate out the connection $\Gamma^{\lambda}_{\mu\nu}$ and keep the metric $g_{\mu\nu}$. Eddington & Schrödinger proposed the [opposite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_unified_field_theories)! Let us analyze this possibility here. Define for later convenience a double-index notation $M=\mu\mu^{\prime}$ and the following shorthand notation

$$\frac{f(R)}{2f^{\prime}(R)}~=:~\hat{f}(R) ~\equiv~ \hat{f}_0+\hat{f}_1R +\hat{f}_2(R).\tag{16}$$

Let us only consider the vacuum

$$T_{\mu\nu}~=~0.\tag{17}$$

from now on. We then have

$$g^M~\stackrel{(4)+(16)+(17)}{\approx}~\hat{f}(R)R^M,\tag{18}$$

where $R^M$ is the inverse Ricci tensor. Equivalently, we have

$$\left(\delta^M_N - \hat{f}_1 R^M R_N\right) g^N~\stackrel{(16)+(18)}{\approx}~\left(\hat{f}_0+f_2(R) \right)R^M.\tag{19}$$

So we get a fixed-point equation for the inverse metric

$$g^N~\stackrel{(19)}{\approx}~\left(\delta^N_M +\frac{\hat{f}_1}{1-d\hat{f}_1} R^N R_M\right)\left(\hat{f}_0+\hat{f}_2(R) \right)R^M$$
$$~=~ \frac{1}{1-d\hat{f}_1}\left(\hat{f}_0+\hat{f}_2\left(g^MR_M\right) \right)R^N.\tag{20}$$

Let us specialize to Einstein gravity (9). Then

$$\hat{f}_0~=~-\Lambda;\qquad\hat{f}_1~=~\frac{1}{2};\qquad\hat{f}_2(R)~=~0.\tag{21}$$

The inverse metric becomes

$$g^N~\stackrel{(20)+(21)}{\approx}~\frac{2\Lambda}{d-2}R^N.\tag{22}$$

And hence 
$$R~\stackrel{(22)}{\approx}~\frac{2d}{d-2}\Lambda,\tag{23}$$

and

$$g_{\mu\nu}~\stackrel{(2)+(22)}{\approx}~\frac{d-2}{2\Lambda}R_{\mu\nu}(\Gamma).\tag{24}$$

So the [EH Lagrangian density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein%E2%80%93Hilbert_action) becomes [Born-Infeld](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born%E2%80%93Infeld_model)-like:

$${\cal L}(\Gamma)~\stackrel{(1)+(17)+(23)+(24)}{\approx}~\frac{1}{\kappa}\left(\frac{d-2}{2\Lambda}\right)^{\frac{d}{2}-1}\sqrt{-\det(R_{\mu\nu}(\Gamma))}.\tag{25}$$

Note that the Eddington-Schrödinger action (25) only works for a non-zero [cosmological constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmological_constant) $\Lambda\neq 0$.

Comment: Further references: 1. http://arxiv.org/abs/0805.1726 2. http://dx.doi.org/10.12942/lrr-2010-3