# Why does the Palatini formalism of GR work?

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism

We can get the Einstein field equations of GR from the [Einstein-Hilbert action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein%E2%80%93Hilbert_action) via two distinct methods:

First, by taking the metric as the only degree of freedom, and imposing right away that the connection is the Levi-Civita connection. In that case the Lagrangian will be a functional of the metric only since the Levi-Civita connection is expressible in terms of derivatives of the metric.

Second, we can follow the [Palatini method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palatini_variation): Take the metric and the connection as independent degrees of freedom and vary with respect to both. It happens curiously that the Euler-Lagrange equations for the connection will just be the condition that it must be the Levi-Civita connection.

It seems to be a wonderful coincidence that we get exactly the condition that the connection must be Levi-Civita one, thus recovering the Einstein field equations. So my question is: Why does this work? Is there any deeper mathematical reason why we get the right answer?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/141550/2451

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The deep mathematical mechanism behind this is *[Cartan geometry](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Cartan%20geometry)*. In Cartan geometry all geometric structures in manifolds (Riemannian, pseudo-Riemannian, complex, holomorphic, conformal, etc.) are expressed in terms of [G-structures](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/G-structure) with [integrability conditions](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/integrability+of+G-structures), which in first order is [torsion freedom](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/torsion%20of%20a%20G-structure).

The [first order formulation of gravity](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/first-order+formulation+of+gravity) that you are are referring to witnesses the fact that the Cartan-geometric description of pseudo-Riemannian geometry is equivalent to the one in terms of symmetric rank-2 tensors.

The same still applies to supergravity, its usual first-order formulation expresses super-Riemannian structure in terms of [super-Cartan geometry](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/super-Cartan+geometry). In fact higher dimensional supergravity is expressed in terms of [higher Cartan geometry](http://ncatlab.org/schreiber/show/Higher+Cartan+Geometry) (to take the higher form fields into account).

Here is a little known fact in this context ([Candiello-Lechner 93](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/torsion+constraints+in+supergravity#Examples11dSuGra)): generally the equations of motion of first-order (super-)gravity imply that (the bosonic component of) the (super-)torsion vanishes. But for 11-dimensional supergravity this implication goes the other way around: just requiring the (bosonic component of the) super-torsion to vanish is here already equivalent to the equations of motion. (Requiring the full supertorsion to vanish is equivalent to the *bosonic* Einstein equations in 11d!) Hence in 11d we may do away with the Palatini action and simply require torsion-freedom.

Comment: Nice funny fact. Is there any interesting application for this fact?

Comment: The interesting application is supposedly in finding a microscopic formulation of M-theory. There are comments in this direction around slide 84 here: http://ncatlab.org/schreiber/show/Equivariant+Cohomotopy+and+Branes