# Variation principle in spacetime with torsion

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor

I wish to study curved spacetime with torsion, however, the trouble is how do I go about with the variational principle? Should I assume the connection $\Gamma^{\alpha}_{\beta\gamma}$ and the metric $g_{\mu\nu}$ as independent variables? Maybe this is fine when metricity is relaxed but what if metricity is imposed i.e. $\nabla_{\mu}g_{\alpha\beta} = 0$ then $$\partial_{\mu}g_{\alpha\beta}-\Gamma^{\lambda}_{~~~\alpha\mu}g_{\lambda\beta}-\Gamma^{\lambda}_{~~~\beta\mu}g_{\alpha\lambda} = 0$$ then clearly the connection is not independent of the metric. Please advice.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/141550/2451

Comment: @Qmechanic No, it is not related.

Comment: Well, the Palatini formalism is sort of the dual situation, where the connection is not metric but the torsion is non-dynamical.

Comment: @Qmechanic But my question is what if the connection is metric? Then the connection and the metric are related via the metricity conditions above, in such a case, what is the procedure for the variation of the action. Clearly, it's a different question. 'Sort of' doesn't answer my question.