# Are there any $f(R, T)$ models of gravity?

Tags: general-relativity, modified-gravity

For the past few months I have been studying $f(R)$ models of gravity. Recently I came cross $f(R, T)$ modified models of gravity. For the past few days I have tried to work out the difference between the two models. The problem is that while there are several models of $f(R)$ gravity, I couldn't find any models of $f(R,T)$ gravity. My question Are there any $f(R, T)$ models of gravity?

Comment: By T, do you mean the stress energy tensor?

Comment: The stress energy tensor itself derives from the Lagrangian, so it is a bit weird that it would be in the Lagrangian itself.

Comment: $T$ in $f(T)$ is torsion

Comment: @innisfree, I know that there $f(T)$ models and $f(R)$ models, but are there any models of $f(R, T)$ gravity.

Comment: For more on [torsion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsion_tensor), see e.g. also [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/137738/2451) Phys.SE post.

Comment: @MrDi the $T$ argument is not the torsion itself, but a scalar construction quadratic in the torsion tensor. It is like a Yang--Mills Lagrangian, but composed of three terms due to other possible contractions of the indices.