# Particle spin as evidence of space-time torsion

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, quantum-spin, fermions

Why cannot we say that spin of "fundamental" particles is exactly an evidence or "proof" of space-time torsion?

Remark: spin is generally a source of torsion when gravity couples to fermions, so...Why can not be said spin is torsion in disguise?

Comment: Because it's not.

Comment: Do you have a proposed mechanism for why these two should be related? As it stands I can't think of any reason this should be the case. Please go into more detail with your reasoning if you want a good answer. Also, possibly relevant [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/137738/spacetime-torsion-the-spin-tensor-and-intrinsic-spin-in-einstein-cartan-theory?rq=1)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spacetime Torsion, the Spin tensor, and intrinsic spin in Einstein-Cartan theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/137738/)

Comment: there is some disconnected/ _unconventional_ research into this area linking QM to fluid dynamics, solitons, and pilot wave hydrodynamics theories, reminds me of electron cycles Zitterbewegung https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zitterbewegung try dropping by [chat] sometime for more investigation

Comment: There is no particular reason for spin to be a source of torsion. Dirac spinors can be coupled to ordinary torsion-free GR with no problem.  Some people like Einstein-Cartan for aesthetic reasons, but it is not logically required for spinning particles.