# Difference between a stress energy tensor and an effective stress energy tensor?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

As I was working through this article by Bronnikov regarding Einstein–Cartan theory:

Bronnikov, K. A., & Galiakhmetov, A. M. (2015). Wormholes without exotic matter in Einstein–Cartan theory. Gravitation and Cosmology, 21(4), 283–288. doi:10.1134/s0202289315040027

He discusses a stress energy tensor and an effective stress energy tensor see his (10). It is a non-minimally coupled scalar field reproduced here for convienece:

$T^{(eff)}_{ab}[\phi]=T_{ab}[\phi]+\kappa^{-1}\Lambda_{ab}$

Where $\Lambda_{ab}$ is a spin piece, and $\kappa$ is the Einstein field equation constant. **My question is**, what makes this important? To clarify, there are still pieces in $T_{ab}[\phi]$ which couple to spin, so it is not like we have completely broken those pieces off. $\Lambda_{ab}[\phi]$ is a piece made only/entirely from spin.

Any thoughts either mathematical or physical would be greatly appreciated! Anything that you think would help clarify please ask! Thanks! ^^

P.S. The following post discusses ECSK theory and some of the relevant topics. Thought it might help! [Spacetime Torsion, the Spin tensor, and intrinsic spin in Einstein-Cartan theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/137738/spacetime-torsion-the-spin-tensor-and-intrinsic-spin-in-einstein-cartan-theory)

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics stack exchange!